# UnitTest add item to list and check if exists

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, moq

I want to test if my code works properly so I am writing some unit tests for it.

I want to check when and item in my list with the same values is added again it should return false.

I do not really understand how to set this up. I hope some can help me out.
Below my code

GuestResponseRepository

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using PartyInvites.Abstract;

namespace PartyInvites.Models
{
    public class GuestResponseRepository : IRepository

    {
        private static List<GuestResponse> responses = new List<GuestResponse>();

        IEnumerable<GuestResponse> IRepository.GetAllResponses()
        {
            return responses;
        }

        bool IRepository.AddResponse(GuestResponse response)
        {
            if (responses.Any(x => x.Email == response.Email)) //here
            {
                if (responses.Any(x => x.WillAttend == response.WillAttend)) //here
                {
                    return false;
                }

                var attend = responses.First(x => x.Email == response.Email && x.WillAttend != response.WillAttend);
                attend.WillAttend = response.WillAttend;
                return true;
            }

            responses.Add(response);
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

My interface which communicates with the `GuestResponseRepository`

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Text;
 using System.Threading.Tasks;
 using PartyInvites.Models;

namespace PartyInvites.Abstract
{
    public interface IRepository
    {
        IEnumerable<GuestResponse> GetAllResponses();
        bool AddResponse(GuestResponse response);
    }
}
```

A piece of my Homecontroller

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using PartyInvites.Models;
using PartyInvites.Abstract;

namespace PartyInvites.Controllers {
    public class HomeController : Controller {
        private IRepository repository;

        public HomeController(IRepository iRepository)
        {
            this.repository = iRepository;
        }


        [HttpGet]
        public ViewResult RsvpForm() {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ViewResult RsvpForm(GuestResponse guestResponse) {
            if (ModelState.IsValid) {

                bool result = repository.AddResponse(guestResponse);
                ViewBag.Response = result;

                repository.AddResponse(guestResponse);                
                return View("Thanks", guestResponse);
            }
            else
            {
                // there is a validation error
                return View();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My UnitTest what I got so far

```
using System;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using PartyInvites.Abstract;
using PartyInvites.Controllers;
using PartyInvites.Models;
using Moq;

namespace Aanmelden
{
    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void FirstResponse()
        {
            //Arange
            Mock<IRepository> mock = new Mock<IRepository>();
            mock.Setup(m => m.AddResponse()).Returns(new GuestResponse[] {
            new GuestResponse {Name = "Valheru", Email = "valheru@hotmail.com", Phone = "12345678", WillAttend = true}
            });

            HomeController controller = new HomeController(mock.Object);
            //Act
            new GuestResponse
            {
                Name = "Valheru",
                Email = "valheru@hotmail.com",
                Phone = "12345678",
                WillAttend = true
            };

            //Assert
            if viewbag.response = result == false test succeeded

        }
    }
}
```

for some reason `mock.Setup(m => m.**AddResponse**()).Returns(new GuestResponse[] {...`
"AddResponse" aint right says Visual Studio ->

> there is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal
>   parameter 'response' of IRepository.AddResponse(GuestReponse)

I am also no sure about my Act piece of code and I lost it totally with the Assert part. I hope someone can help me out!

Comment: Why are you adding `guestResponse` twice to the repository in the controller action?

Answer (score 0):

you should `It.IsAny<GuestResponse>()` as a paramater in  order to match the signature of your interface

```
    Mock<IRepository> mock = new Mock<IRepository>();
    mock.Setup(m => m.AddResponse(It.IsAny<GuestResponse>())).Returns(true);
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but if I add It.IsAny(GuestResponse) it gives back:  'GuestResponse' is a type, which is not valid in the given context

Answer (score 0):

Based on

> I want to check when an item in my list with the same values is added
>   again it should return false.

You should actually be testing the `GuestResponseRepository` implementation itself and not the controller.

```
[TestMethod]
public void Duplicate_Added_Should_Return_False {
    //Arrange
    var sut = new GuestResponseRepository();
    var model = new GuestResponse
    {
        Name = "Valheru",
        Email = "valheru@hotmail.com",
        Phone = "12345678",
        WillAttend = true
    };

    sut.AddResponse(model);

    var expected = false;

    //Act
    var actual = sut.AddResponse(model);

    //Assert
    Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Nkosi for you repley! I changed my code to what you suggested, but  it looks like response in mock.Setup(m => m.GetAllResponses()).Returns(responses); ain't good. It give back: cannot convert from PartyInvites.Models.GuestResponse to System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<PartyInvites.Models.GuestResponse>

Also the Act part needed some extra usings but that looks fine now :)

Any suggestion about the responses?

Comment: Shouldn't I use the IRepository for testing? Becuase didn't use dependency injecting for nothing (in the future I am gonna GuestResponseRepository to a database)

Comment: IRepository is an abstraction that is used as dependency to other classes. based on initial question you wanted to test the logic of the repository. So then the implementation is what needed to be tested.

Comment: Thats sounds logical :) The only thing that doesnt work from your code is the sut.AddResponse. It says that GuestResponseRepository does not contain a definition for AddResponse

Comment: Change `bool IRepository.AddResponse(GuestResponse response)` in the class to `bool AddResponse(GuestResponse response)`. Or explicitly cast the sut to `IRepository` before calling the method